# operator definition not working right

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a comparison operator but I'm getting the following errors

> whole.cpp(384): error C2270: '==' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
>   whole.cpp(384): error C2805: binary 'operator ==' has too few parameters
>   whole.cpp(384): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator

I can't seem to pin down the problem though so here is the code

this is the operator implementation in the class

```
bool operator==(const DateC& p) const
{
    return ( DateC::DateC()== p.DateC() );
};

#include <assert.h>
int main(unsigned int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DateC f(29,33,11);

    DateC::testAdvancesWrap();
};

void DateC::testAdvancesWrap(void)
{
    DateC d;
    cout << "DateC::testAdvanceWrap()" << endl ;
    cout << "*********************" << endl << endl ;
    cout << "\tCHECK ADVANCE MULTIPLES:" << endl;
    cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
    d.setDay(1);
    d.setMonth(12);
    d.setYear(1999); 
    prettyPrint(d);
    cout << "ACTION: set date 01-Dec-1999, advance, 31 days, 1 month and 1 year ->" << endl;
    d.advance(1,1,31);

    assert( d == DateC(1,2,2001) );

    cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

    prettyPrint(d);
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

the rest of the functions working fine it's only the assert()

Comment: I don't think `the rest of the functions working fine`. Your `operator ==` is not a member function, and yet it's `const`-qualified. It accepts one argument, and it should accept two (unless you make it a member function, of course). Your program should not compile even if you remove the `assert(...)`

Comment: The errors are pretty clear what the problems are. Information about [C2270](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8tw34k0(v=vs.110).aspx), [C2805](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z50y5wk(v=vs.110).aspx) and [C2274](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kst1dcx0(v=vs.110).aspx) is available online.

Comment: The code works fine without the assert function, please sugest a fix not a link

Comment: To provide a link is to suggest a fix. Most all the error docs on MS have code examples. Did you bother to follow them?

Comment: The links are provided so that you _learn_ the information you need about the errors and how they relate to what you are trying to do. The links include descriptions and enough inforamtion on how to fix the problem.

Comment: yes fixed loads from the links but not this one so thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement comparison operators as member functions or free functions. To implement it as a free function as you are trying to do you need to accept two arguments - the value on the left hand side of `=` and the value on the right hand side of `=`. The example below shows how to properly do this.

```
struct Date
{
    int variable_;
};

bool operator==(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs)
{
    return lhs.variable_ == rhs.variable_;
}
```

To implement the comparison operator as a member function you only need to take one argument which is the value on the right hand size of `=`. The object owning the comparison operator being executed is the value on the left hand side of `=`. In this case the operator should be const qualified.

```
struct Date
{
    int variable_;

    bool operator==(const Date& rhs) const
    {
        return variable_ == rhs.variable_;
    }
};
```

In all cases the argument should be taken as a `const` reference to allow the use of rvalues (temporaries).

Comment: hi sure but what if I want to evaluate the first class constructor against  rhs constructor ?in the code above

Comment: Use `Date() == Date()` to do the comparison.